# How to make a carousel follow a link after its finished its event?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, carousel, setinterval

community, so I've got this website https://stfn.herokuapp.com, which is using a jQuery carousel. I can't figure out a way how to go to a link *after* the carousel finished moving. Do you guys think setInterval() would work best? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In [the docs](https://github.com/sgb-io/jquery.circular-carousel) for the carousel you're using it has:

```
/* Fires after an item finishes it's activate animation */
carousel.on('itemActive', function(e, item) {
   //do something with $(item)
});
```

You can put `document.location.href = "http://test.com";` or similar inside there to change the page once the carousel animation is complete

Comment: Hey Brett, thanks for the answer! I tried it there and it didn't work, I think there's some kind of a missmatch (maybe in the naming?) in the carousel's code and I couldn't figure out where it is located..

[EDIT] oh damn it works, but for some reason it immediately redirects to another page (when i just load the page)

Comment: I think the reason is because the `itemActive` event is being called as soon as the page loads (since the first item in the carousel becomes active). Easiest fix is to have a new variable which is initially set to false, then once the user has clicked set to true and check for that before changing the page. Something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpPqva

Comment: Woo it works! the only thing is that if I click on an item which is further in the carousel, then the redirect loads before the carousel manages to reach the item that was clicked.. I'm wondering what could be a way to detect when the carousel is completely done with all its actions?

Comment: Awesome :) I thought that event would only fire when the animation is finished. I've got a hack that will work, I'll make you a working example quick and post it here in a few minutes

Comment: Hey Brett, thanks for all, if you find a way to detect when the animations are finished let me know, I'd be grateful to the grave!

Comment: Sorry got busy at work but will send you something later :)

Comment: @JurgisLietunovas [here's a bit of a hacky way](http://brettgregson.com/stackoverflow/) to introduce the delay based on the distance between the clicked item and the current item in the circle (view the source, specifically the script.js file). So you would change the page in the `goToLink` function. I haven't really tested it but it seems to work :)

Comment: Hey Brett, you're a lifesaver, I was was trying to figure it out for hours, still so much to learn.. I've linked all the pages https://stfn.herokuapp.com/
if you ever need some design help let me know!